# How do I Join ORG table to ORG GROUP table

Tags: sql, join

[image: ORG tables]

How do I join two tables with the SQL Query in the image attached?  Currently is pulling no data.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: You are joining two tables, old style implicit join.

Comment: You need to work out the correct join key(s) `o.org_desc=og.org_group_desc` is definitely not a join key - they don't match do they? So remove that at least

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the report I need

[Example report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOld3.png)

I think this would work, you can change the type of JOIN according to your requirement:

```
SELECT 
o.DMN_ID,
o.ORG_ID,
o.ORG_DESC,
o.ORG_TYP_ID,
o.LST_UDR_USR,
o.LST_UPD_TSTMP,

og.ORG_GROUP_ID,
og.ORG_GROUP_DESC,
og.LST_UPD_USR,
og.LST_UPD_TSTMP

FROM PA_ORG o INNER JOIN
PA_ORG_GROUP og ON  
o.ORG_ID = og.ORG_GROUP_ID
and o.ORG_DESC = og.ORG_GROUP_DESC
```

Comment: Inner join pulls no data.  Left only pulls left and Right only pulls right. Full Join pulls nothing

Comment: Why do you put one join condition in the ON clause, and the other one in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Then that means values with ORG_ID in PA_ORG table does not exist in ORG_GROUP_ID column in PA_ORG_GROUP table. If you could provide sample data, it will be very useful to answer this question.

Comment: @jarlh I just wanted to give an example where he can add all the necessary conditions in JOIN as well as add other conditions in WHERE.

Comment: @SherrySievers: if a left join returns data and and right join returns data then it's impossible that a full outer join returns nothing

Comment: For example - I have 217 different Organizations and 22 different Organization groups.  I need to be able to have a report that will show me which Organization Group connects to which Organization.  So I need to connect ORG GROUP to ORG

Comment: @SherrySievers: Again: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48342353/edit) your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: I already mentioned in my comments above - your join keys are wrong. `o.ORG_DESC = og.ORG_GROUP_DESC` are not going to match. It seems like you're just guessing here. I don't know why people ask questions if they can't make the basic effort to take note of comments